# How to avoid hardcoded names in DelimitedLineTokenizer names?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am using DelimitedLineTokenizer to read from a txt file using FlatFileItemReader. However, is there a way to avoid hardcoding the "names" property of the fields ? Instead can we use any bean ?

```
<bean id="employeeReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="#{jobParameters['input.file.name']}" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="empId,empName,empAge" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                    <property name="targetType" value="com.example.Employee" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is not because the result of the `LineTokenizer`'s work is a `FieldSet`.  A `FieldSet` is like a `ResultSet` for a file.  So just like in a `ResultSet`, we need to reference each "column" by something which in this case is the name.  The `LineTokenizer` has no insight into where the data is ending up (what the object looks like) so we have no way to introspect it.  If you wanted to take a more dynamic approach, you'd want to implement your own `LineMapper` that combines the two functions together allowing for that type of introspection.

As always, pull requests are appreciated!

Comment: Thanks Michael. But the values of names are not seemed to be used. It just acts as a place holder. So in that case is it really needed ? It could have been just the String array of size = no.of columns. Is my understanding right ? or is there a siginificance for this name values?

Comment: without the names, the BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper can't do its magic - matching  the fieldSet (name:value) to the Object (setName(value))

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Michael Minella's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32995337/4140367), here's what you can do :

You can use a value such as `#{jobParameter['key']}`, `#{jobExecutionContext['key']}` or `#{stepExecutionContext['key']}` in the `<property name="names">` tag.

This means that you can have a step or a listener which does your business logic and save the result at any time in the `ExecutionContext` :

```
stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put(key, value);
```

Keep in mind though, that the field `names` of a `DelimitedLineTokenizer` needs a String (well not really, but close enough), not a bean.